# Android development - adding own application to "share vCalendar"

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to add own application to Calendar "share via" menu, by adding intent filter to
manifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/x-vCalendar" />
</intent-filter>
```

It works fine on Samsung phones, but not on HTC.
What do I need to do to make it work on HTC phone?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try switching to more-current iCalendar format and using `text/calendar` for the MIME type.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that HTC uses proprietary intent "android.intent.action.LAUNCH_MSG_COMPOSE" to share vCard via....

Answer (score 1):

I do NOT think you have missed anything. I'vd tried as you do on our phone, it worked. And we found Android source has a bug in Calendar when sharing event via Gmail - Gmail will hangs because it does not have READ_CALENDAR permission. Checking our reference HTC phones and found they have removed the Gmail option and add Email.
I guess that HTC's engineer use hard coded menu instead of using createrChooser when sharing calendar. And that might caused your program not shown in list.

Comment: Wow! john  found that real reason - HTC changed the intent from SEND to LAUNCH_MSG_COMPOSE. That's a way to avoid Gmail's bug.